# Problem in Deploying AIR Application

Tags: air

I am new to Adobe AIR and I was following the steps given in the site :
"http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/introduction-to-adobe-air/", to create my first AIR application.
I was almost successful in creating my first AIR application but at the last step of Deploying AIR Application, after the successful creation of certificate when I am trying to create the.air file. I am getting the error :
"Could not generate timestamp: Connection refused: connect".

Can you please help me in resolving the issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a short-term workaround, you can specify "-tsa none" on the ADT command line. (If you are using Flash Pro or Builder, there should be an option in the UI). -tsa none disables timestamps.

A timestamp requires an internet connection in order to get a signed timestamp token from a server. This is used to verify that your certificate was valid when the app was signed. Without a timestamp, your app won't be installable after your code signing certificate expires. With a timestamp, your app installer will not expire.

Proxy connections are sometimes the issue. Since ADT is a Java program, you have to configure the Java proxy settings if this is the source of the trouble.